I want to Chance a Text more than one time i Click on the Button
but nothing happens. what i habe to chance in this Code?
can u help me..
this is for a TextAdventure Game that talks to you and change the text after your answer in the input field.
function functionfirstAnswer() 
    {

    let storyLine = new Array();
    let nextStoryLine = 0;
    storyLine[0] = "Hallo, " + userInput.value + " weist du noch was passiert ist?";
    storyLine[1] = "text one.";
    storyLine[2] = "text two.";
    storyLine[3] = "";
    storyLine[4] = "";
    storyLine[5] = "";
    storyLine[6] = "";
    storyLine[7] = "";
    storyLine[8] = "";
    storyLine[9] = "";



    let userInput = document.querySelector("#userInput01");
    let message = document.getElementById("#messageFirst");

    message.innerHTML = [++nextStoryLine]; 

    }

here is the HTML
 <input type="text" id="userInput01" placeholder="">
    <button id="firstButton" onclick="functionfirstAnswer()">Antwort</button>



function functionfirstAnswer() {
  let storyLine = new Array();
  let nextStoryLine = 0;
  storyLine[0] = "Hallo, " + userInput.value + " weist du noch was passiert ist?";
  storyLine[1] = "text one.";
  storyLine[2] = "text two.";
  storyLine[3] = "";
  storyLine[4] = "";
  storyLine[5] = "";
  storyLine[6] = "";
  storyLine[7] = "";
  storyLine[8] = "";
  storyLine[9] = "";



  let userInput = document.querySelector("#userInput01");
  let message = document.getElementById("#messageFirst");

  message.innerHTML = [++nextStoryLine];

}
<input type="text" id="userInput01" placeholder="">
<button id="firstButton" onclick="functionfirstAnswer()">Antwort</button>




nextStoryLine is a local variable that will get the value 0 every time the function is called. You need to keep the state outside of the function to let it keep its value.

You need to move both userInput and message up. They must exist before they're used. Also, consider using array literals and not new Array

In this line:  message.innerHTML = [++nextStoryLine];
Did you mean: message.innerHTML =storyLine [++nextStoryLine];
?

And in addition, you do not have a tag with such an ID: #messageFirst

The userInput variable is being accessed before it's defined.
You're trying to access the messageFirst element using getElementById with #, which is incorrect.
live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/o089g6d5/
Here's the corrected code:
let nextStoryLine = 0; // Define nextStoryLine outside the function
let userInput = document.querySelector("#userInput01"); // Define userInput outside the function
let message = document.getElementById("messageFirst"); // Define message outside the function

    function functionfirstAnswer() {
        let storyLine = [
            "Hallo, " + userInput.value + " weist du noch was passiert ist?",
            "text one.",
            "text two.",
            // Add more text lines here as needed
        ];
    
        message.innerHTML = storyLine[nextStoryLine];
        nextStoryLine = (nextStoryLine + 1) % storyLine.length; // Increment nextStoryLine and ensure it loops back
    }

And the HTML:
 <input type="text" id="userInput01" placeholder="">
<button id="firstButton" onclick="functionfirstAnswer()">Antwort</button>
<div id="messageFirst"></div>

